# how can i read cookie generated by web browser from activex control

Tags: visual-c++, com, activexobject, activex-documents

I want to read and fetch the contents of a cookie generated by web browser from activex control. I dont want to read the cookie from javascript and pass it to activex control. I want read the cookie directly from activex control. If it is possible then suggest me the APIs for that and also same thing I have to achieve using NPAPI also (so please suggest APIs in here also). So looking forward for some positive answers.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is

1) hook up Web Browser events, using for example this sample [How to sink HTML document events for WebBrowser host](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/246247)

2) once you get a hold on the loaded [IHTMLDocument2](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574.aspx) document interface, just read the value of the cookie property:

```
CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pDoc // get document from event as shown in the sample.

// read the cookie
CComBSTR cookie;
hr = pDoc->get_cookie(&cookie);
```

More on this here: [Handling HTML Element Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb508508.aspx)

Note: for NSAPI I suggest you write another question with other tags as this is a totally different world.

Comment: Can I access cookies marked as HttpOnly via IHTMLDocument2::cookie inside ActiveX?